# Finding a Name of an most sold item in my library(mysql)

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have homework and ı stucked at one point. I have 7 table for my database.These are `products-books-movies-musics-transactions-users` and for many to many relationship there is table `transproduct`. So i wanna find de most sold item in the database with product's name and type and number of sales of that product. İn short transproduct holds the transactionid,productid and quantity,product holds the name,type and etc.
I wrote a query like this:

```
select Barcode,sum(quantity) 
  from transproduct 
  group by Barcode;
```

and it gives me the barcode of a product and the number of sales of that item; for example;

```
12345  15

13452  2
etc...
```

so i tried to use both of the tables and wrote someting like that

```
select Barcode,max(summ) from(
select Barcode,sum(quantity) as summ 
  from transproduct 
  group by Barcode ) as t1;
```

but it doesn't give me the product id of most sold item it gives the minimum product id and number of sales of max sold product. I want to get a table like this

```
productName|productType|Quantity

Back To Black|Music|53
```

I am so confused so i know i couldn't explain myself clearly but thanks if u can help...

The tables I am using :

```
create table transproduct(
transactionID char(9),
Barcode char(5),
quantity integer(5),
constraint pktransproduct primary key (transactionID, Barcode));

alter table transproduct add constraint fktransproducttransaction
foreign key (transactionID) references transactions(transactionID);

alter table transproduct add constraint fktransproductproduct
foreign key (Barcode) references product(Barcode);
```

and

```
create table product(
Barcode char(5),
productName nvarchar(50),
quantity integer(6),
price double,
ProductType varchar(11),
constraint pkproduct primary key (Barcode));
```

these are some sample data from product

```
'12345', 'A Head Full Of Dreams', '2', '7.5', 'Music'
'46089', 'Ride The Lightning ', '31', '19.99', 'Music'
'46792', 'Back to Black', '21', '13.5', 'Music'
```

these are some sample data from transproduct

```
'164571349', '13762', '3'
'496272753', '14532', '13'
'365725914', '14532', '2'
```

to be clear as you can see the product '14532' sold 15 times and its the most sold item so i wanna get table like

```
'Of Mice And Men','Book','15'
```

now im using this query and it works but i dont think its efficient

```
select productName,ProductType,r from(
select Barcode as b ,max(summ) as r from(
select Barcode,sum(quantity) as summ 
  from transproduct 
  group by Barcode order by  sum(quantity) desc )as t1)as t2,product where    b=product.Barcode;
```

Comment: Have a look at what the ORDER BY (and LIMIT) clauses can do for you.

Comment: Show some sample data with your result and the expected result

Comment: I used some order by and lots of nested select i know my query is not efficient at all but it will do for now i thinks. Sorry for bothering you and thanks for order by advice^^ if i can finish all other assignment i will come back and ask this question with more specific data ^^

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to Group it by Product name if you have that in your transproduct table.

```
    select Barcode,sum(quantity) 
    from transproduct 
     group by productname;
```

Would be better If you can provide schema of both the table and some sample data.

Comment: I dont have productname in transproduct i will edit my question with the tables and some sample data in a minute